# Changing color of span text with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, razor

I have some some CSS that changes the color of my Validation text color. I would like the color to change to green when a checkbox is checked. My JQuery doesn't seem to like the reference to the tag. Any suggestions?

**Razor HTML**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.textBox)
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.textBox,"Required", new { @class = "disableRequired" })
```

**CSS**

```
span.disableRequired.field-validation-error{
   color:yellow;
}
```

**JQuery doesn't work**

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {
     $("span.disableRequired.field-validation-error").css("color", "green");
});
```

Comment: Please post your HTML as well.

Comment: try to make a http://jsfiddle.net/ so we can see better the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your JavaScript code is fine, if there are no errors in the console (check Google Chrome) than it should work just fine. [Here is a JsFiddle which proves it's correct JavaScript code](http://jsfiddle.net/PGEGf/).  You're problem must be elsewhere.

```
$('span.disabled').click(function () {
    $('.disabled').css("color", "red");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying that it wasn't my JQuery I ended up trying it on an earlier version and it worked so I changed something I wasn't supposed to sometime today. But it works now so thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution

**CSS**

```
.greentext
{
    color: green;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#checkBox').click(function () {

    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $("span.disableRequired.field-validation-error").addClass("greentext");
    }
    else {
        $("span.disableRequired.field-validation-error").removeClass("greentext");
    }
});
```

Comment: Could also use toggleClass, since it will be trigger by a checkbox, which only has 2 possible states.